# Dropdown menu not showing when put into navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML piece that should make a dropdown menu. It works fine but when i put it in my "navbar" it would be limited to the size of the "navbar". If i place it outside the navbar i can't place it so it looks like it is in the "navbar". Any idea what to do?

This is how it looks:
[image: Dropdown in navbar]

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div.navBar {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

#Logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    top: 0%;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -75%);
    width: 100%;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {
    display:inline-block;
    align-content: center;
    width: 15%;
    }

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change color of links on hover */
ul.topnav li a:hover {color: #555;}

/* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li {
    display: none;
    }
}

#User {
    postion: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -90%;
    top: 100%;
}


/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: auto;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover */
.dropbtn:hover {
    color: #555;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    overflow-y: 1000;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
 <div class="navBar">
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li><a href="https://case-clicker.000webhostapp.com"><img id="Logo" alt="Logo" src="/img/logotext.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li><div class="dropdown">
                        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><img alt="userAvatar" src="<?=$steamprofile['avatar']?>"><?=$steamprofile['personaname']?></button>
                        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? sample output would help us understand your question

Comment: @Roljhon see the edited post

Comment: The reason why it is limited to the size of the navbar, might be because the navbar and topnav has a overflow: hidden. That will hide anything, overflowing that element.

Comment: @Roljhon That just makes it float on the bottom of the side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `overflow:hidden` from the `#navBar` and the `#topnav`

(*also fix `postion` to `position` on `#User`*)

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div.navBar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
#Logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  top: 0%;
  position: absolute;
}
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%);
  width: 100%;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.topnav li {
  display: inline-block;
  align-content: center;
  width: 15%;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change color of links on hover */

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  color: #555;
}
/* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li {
    display: none;
  }
}
#User {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -90%;
  top: 100%;
}
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: auto;
}
/* Dropdown button on hover */

.dropbtn:hover {
  color: #555;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow-y: 1000;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <li>
      <a href="https://case-clicker.000webhostapp.com">
        <img id="Logo" alt="Logo" src="/img/logotext.png">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
          <img alt="userAvatar" src="<?=$steamprofile['avatar']?>">
          <?=$steamprofile[ 'personaname']?>
        </button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This now have fixed it so that the hole button is showed on the navbar, but the dropdown is still not showing

Comment: use `$('#myDropdown').toggle('show');` instead @McMuffin

Comment: @Roljhon instead of what?

Comment: suppose you should know where your toggle is but for the sake of it, instead of `document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");`

Comment: Ah of cource, i'm just a bit tierd

Comment: @Roljhon It dropsdown it just only shows a bit of the top and then every thing else in the dropdown is hidden

Comment: @McMuffin I'm not pretty sure if I really get what you want, try to update your OP and be more specific on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Roljhon as mentioned in my OP it works perfectly when not placed in the "navbar" but when it is placed in it, it only shows what can be inside the "navbar"

Comment: @McMuffin did you run the code in the answer (*and open it in full screen*) ? What does not work ?

Comment: @McMuffin it would be great if you could provide how you solved it by updating your post. This will help others too

Comment: I just changed the code as in the accepted answer, should I still do it?